# Relocate Action Center in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, desktop-customization, productivity, action-center

I use Windows 10 Pro 1709 64-bit with a vertical Taskbar on the left (I need as much vertical space as possible on a laptop's widescreen due to my workflow). Calling the Action Center with a button located on the bottom left corner (`|□|`) results in a panel appearing on the right screen border, which requires the cursor to travel all the way across the screen if one wants to click things there, and back to left.

How can I reposition the area where Action Center appears? To clarify what I mean here is an ASCII sketch:

```
Current Action Center behaviour:
+----------------------------------+
|T|                       | ACTION |
|A|                       | CENTER |
|S|                       |        |
|K|                       |        |
|B|                       |        |
|A|                       |________|
|R|                       |__|__|__|
|□|                       |__|__|__|
+----------------------------------+

Anticipated Action Center behaviour:
+----------------------------------+
|T| ACTION |                       |
|A| CENTER |                       |
|S|        |                       |
|K|        |                       |
|B|        |                       |
|A|________|                       |
|R|__|__|__|                       |
|□|__|__|__|                       |
+----------------------------------+
```

P. S. Please *do not* suggest to relocate the Taskbar itself. I used this layout for years and everything except for the new Action Center clicks for me just fine. Also feel free to suggest any third-party tweaking tool that can help.